# Getting mixed results converting images to .ICO with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, images, icons, conversion

EDIT: I managed to get it to scale properly with this as the ffmpeg command:

```
-vf "thumbnail,scale='if(gt(iw,ih),256,trunc(oh*a/2)*2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),trunc(ow/a/2)*2,256)'"
```

That works but on portrait images there's a white strip at the bottom with a pattern to it. This is as close as I have got to it working properly.

Original post:

This works for a 419 wide x 313 high gif file:

```
ffmpeg -i "my.gif" -vf scale=256:-1 "my.ico"
```

The resulting ico file is 256 wide x 191 high.
This also works in most other cases for most other images (all different file types and dimensions)

However, the above command does not work for a 1587 wide x 907 high tiff file I tried it on:

```
ffmpeg -i "my.tiff" -vf scale=256:-1 "my.ico"
```

The resulting ico file is a damaged/corrupted file that's 4 bytes in size.

I tried the above command with a 230 x 245 png file and just like the tiff file, that also comes out as a damaged/corrupted file that's 4 bytes in size.

I don't want to change the aspect ratio, but if I do, and change this part:

```
scale=256:-1
```

To this:

```
scale=256:256
```

Then the png file I mentioned above does come out OK, but the tiff file still doesn't.

I wonder if there's a command that works in all cases, keeping images 256 wide by whatever it comes out to keep aspect ratio.

It has to be a simple typo or something?

Cheers folks.

Comment: Share full log of cmd that results in a 4 byte file.

Comment: I can't output a log from ffmpeg. Putting pause in the batch file isn't working. I can't see the error because it just flashes up the command window in a split second. Both the original tiff and png files open in Windows Picture Viewer, they have thumbnails in the folder in Windows, but opening them with Photoshop, it says they are "not the right kind of document". I don't think this can be made to work unless I convert them to something else like bmp or jpg.

Comment: If I convert the tiff file to either bmp or gif, the conversion works, however doing that with the png file, doesn't work. This is a png with transparency, another png file (that will open in Photoshop) converts fine. I don't think this is anything to do with transparency though.

Comment: Add -report and rerun. ffmpeg will generate a text log file.

Comment: OK cheers, it's giving me `Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument` The line above that says `[ico @ 06f40c00] BMP must be 1bit, 4bit, 8bit, 16bit, 24bit, or 32bit` I'll probably put in some sort of sub-thing that just converts the files to BMP first.

Comment: I think the problem is if I have a tall image, it can't do it. Trying to convert the png file to .ico, it says `Unsupported dimensions 256x273 (dimensions cannot exceed 256x256)` so, I wonder if there's some way of putting a safeguard in the command in case an image is tall and thin (as opposed to widescreen looking ones that convert fine). I'm getting two different problems with two different file types but the tiff file problem doesn't matter, I can easily convert to BMP. It's this scaling problem that's the show-stopper! If height exceeds width - it won't do it.

Comment: I got it to work with this:  **-vf "thumbnail,scale='if(gt(iw,ih),256,trunc(oh*a/2)*2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),trunc(ow/a/2)*2,256)'"**